# Is it possible to get difference between two columns which are dynamically pivoted in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting value in the below format for @sql:
Format1:-

```
Customer   Organization_Name  Kpi_Name        [2020-01-23]   [2020-01-24]
    --------------------------------------------------------------
 Adidas         BioLife       Customer Survey      78              78
 Adidas         BioLife       EH&S Audit           52              52
```

This is my sp:-

Below are some parameters in which I am passing values.

```
 Create PROCEDURE [_RUN].[GetMeasureOrganization] @CurrentRundate  DATE,
                                        @PreviousRunDate DATE,
                                                @CustomerName    VARCHAR(100),
                                                @ResultType      NVARCHAR(256)



    AS
         BEGIN

             SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

Here, I am declaring variables:-

```
DECLARE @column AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
     DECLARE @column0 NVARCHAR(MAX);
     DECLARE @column01 NVARCHAR(MAX);
     DECLARE @column1 NVARCHAR(MAX);
     DECLARE @column11 NVARCHAR(MAX);
     DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
     DECLARE @sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX);

     BEGIN
```

This is how I am taking two dates using distinct command.

```
  SELECT @column = COALESCE(@column+',', '')+QUOTENAME([R])
         FROM
         (
             SELECT DISTINCT
                    RunDate R
             FROM _Result.VW_Result
             WHERE RunDate = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @currentRundate)
                   OR RunDate=CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @PreviousRundate)
         ) AS x1;
  --  print @column01
         SET @column0 = ''''+REPLACE(replace(replace(@column, '[', ''), ']', ''), ',', ''',''')+'''';
```

This is my SQL Query part where I am getting values like Format1:-

```
 SELECT @sql = 'select *


FROM
(select CUSTOMER,RunDate,
            Organization_Name,KPI_Name,
            Measure
     FROM _Result.VW_Result where RunDate in ('+@column0+') and CUSTOMER='''+@CustomerName+'''
                AND Result_Type = '''+@ResultType+''') x
PIVOT 
(
    sum(measure)
    for [rundate] in ('+@column+')
) P';
             EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL
                  @sql;
--print @sql

             SELECT @column1 = COALESCE(@column1+',', '')+QUOTENAME(R)
             FROM
             (
                 SELECT DISTINCT
                        RunDate R
                 FROM _Result.VW_Result
                  WHERE RunDate = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @currentRundate)
                       OR RunDate=CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @PreviousRundate)
             ) AS x1;
             PRINT @COLUMN1;
       -- print @sql
             SET @column11 = ''''+REPLACE(replace(replace(@column1, '[', ''), ']', ''), ',', ''',''')+'''';
             SELECT @sql1 = 'select * 
 FROM
(select CUSTOMER,RunDate,
            Organization_Name,KPI_Name,
           Measure
     FROM _Result.VW_Result where RunDate in ('+@column11+') and CUSTOMER='''+@CustomerName+'''
                AND Result_Type = '''+@ResultType+''' ) x
PIVOT 
(
    count(Measure)
    for [rundate] in ('+@column1+')
) P';
--print @sql1    
--group by CUSTOMER,RunDate,
            --Organization_Name,KPI_Name  
             EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL
                  @sql1; 
    -- print @sql      

     END;
}
```

I want to get difference between two pivoted columns just in below format. And, I want to know whether it's possible or not.

```
 Customer   Organization_Name  Kpi_Name    [2020-01-23]   [2020-01-24]  Difference
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Adidas      BioLife       Customer Survey      78          78            0
  Adidas      BioLife       EH&S Audit           52          52            0
```

Comment: That SQL you've provided won't give the results you show us. What is the actual SQL you're running? What about if `RunDate` has more than 2 values (or 1)? What does your actual data look like?

Comment: Can you include the code that gives the output shown

Comment: While dont your insert the result into temp table and from the temp table you write a query to give you the Difference?

Comment: @larnu I have created a Stored Procedure in which, when i pass values i get output like First format which i have included.

Comment: I will post My stored procedure in which upon passing values i am getting output in format mentioned on top.

Comment: That SQL has no column `Kpi_Name`; that SQL and that result set aren't related, as far as we can tell. In fact, that SQL assigns a value to a variable, it won't produce a visible dataset at all.

Comment: @Larnu I have edited and posted my Stored Procedure.